# Mysql implementation and efficiency querying on multiple fields

Tags: mysql, performance, algorithm, indexing

I want to search a table by two fields in MySQL:

```
select * from table where  
90 < x and x < 100 and 
50 < y and y < 60
```

What is the efficiency of this search if optimised? O(log(n))?

And what type of index and algorithm would it be implementing? (Am I correct in saying it would be O(n.log(n)) if using standard B-tree or hash map?)

Thanks

Comment: You should probably be using `BETWEEN` to make what's going on here more clear.

Comment: What execution plan are you getting?

Comment: I haven't done any kind of analysis, I'm a long way from putting this into practice, I'd just like to know in principle what should be achievable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complexity in MySQL is often so unpredictable that to express it in Big-O notation is mostly meaningless. Computer Science type theory about algorithm performance falls apart completely in this context.

The biggest issue is I/O overhead, where as soon as you need to make any sort of disk access there's no way to tell how long the operation will take. It could be a few milliseconds or it could be several seconds depending on how loaded the system is.

Generally you should benchmark to determine the performance characteristics on your particular system and configuration, and even then it only gives you an idea.

These Big-O algorithms are only meaningful if the entire working set is in memory and access time is consistent across all of the associated data.